# IOS Label displayed incorrectly after rotated phone

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, label, uilabel

I do not understand why it sometimes when I rotate the phone:

Original:
[image]

After rotation:

[image]

Normally again, well displayed. Turning bad again.

Comment: I think you need elaborate more. I am not sure, what you really asking. Show us a little bit of code as well.

Comment: Only a standard label: `self.filmTartalom.text = film["leiras"].stringValue`

Comment: what are constraint on that label....? it might be happen because of the constraint.

Comment: I use: Aling trailing to Superview equals 5, leading space to superview equals 5.

Comment: top constraints? bottom constraints? number of lines in the label?

Comment: number of lines 0, bottom space to vetites equals 15, and top space to youtubeimdb equals 15

Comment: how many labels are there ? and which constraints you applied ?

Answer (score 0):

There occurs layout changes when the device orientation is changed. have you tried using `layoutIfNeeded()` after the orientation is changed?

Comment: If i use layoutIfNeeded(), doing it all the time, when rotate display.